# Issue with C# Debugger.Lauch() Method

Tags: c#, debugging, remote-debugging, system.diagnostics

I am debugging a C# windows service using System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(). The development environment is Windows server 2008. The same machine is used by other user as well as server m/c allows multiple login.

My problem is,  when i tried to debug, the breakpoint hits in the other user session. Is there any way to force lauch the debugger on specific user session?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But, that will not help me in launching the debugger in my user session.

Comment: My bad, I think I totally misunderstood you :)

Comment: You can get the user from the other session to notify you, then attach to the process. Is there any reason you cannot do this on your desktop?

Comment: Are you logged into the same account?

Comment: @leppie, i had to debug in deployed env only as I have to call few API which need license.

Comment: @Jon, I tried with my login as well as well as the account of Windows service login. But i am still facing this issue.

Comment: The issue is with the *session*, not the user.  Services run in session 0, the isolated session that is not allowed to interact with the desktop.  A counter-measure against shatter attacks.  Tools + Attach to Process can work.  As long as your service is still unstable and needs debug support, you are much better off running it as a desktop program.

Comment: I tend to set these things up so that the actual work is in a separate dll, and all the service does it start that. Then this can also be hosted in a console app for testing with zero work